# MYSQL: how to create inherit table design

Tags: mysql, inheritance

I would like to design a supertype named `'post'` and two subtypes `'blog_post'` and `'image_post'`.

- The supertype holds `id`, `title`, `time_posted`.
- `'blog_post'` holds `thumbnail`, `body`.
- `'image_post'` holds `image_path`, `category`.

How can I implement this model in MySQL?
How can I insert data into this model to establish complete post of each subtype?

Comment: is this about jpa? i.e. persistence framework?

Answer (score 1):

I think, inheritance in database design is just telling about properties that refers to columns and is like this:

```
Shape { Long Id, String Name }

Circle :: Shape { Long Id, Integer Radius, Long Shape.Id, String Shape.Name }
Square :: Shape { Long Id, Integer Width, Long Shape.Id, String Shape.Name }
```

Goes to:

```
[Shape] table:
Id bigint^
Name varchar(20)

[Circle] table:                       [Square] table
Id bigint^                            Id bigint^
ShapeId bigint*                       ShapeId bigint*
Radius int                            Width int
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no inheritence with tables. There are two common ways to go around this problem:

1) Have just one table and leave columns null:

- ***table post*** (**id_post**, title, time_posted, thumbnail, body, image_path, category)

You would have a constraint to ensure that either thumbnail and body or image_path and category are filled. (MySQL lacks check constraints, so you would write a before insert/update trigger for this.)

2) Have a parent and child tables that you join:

- ***table post*** (**id_post**, title, time_posted, id_blog_post, id_image_post)
- ***table blog_post*** (**id_blog_post**, thumbnail, body)
- ***table image_post*** (**id_image_post**, image_path, category)

There are other ways to address the problem, such as having blog_post and image_post only, both featuring the columns title and time_posted. Or take solution 2 and add id_post to blog_post and image_post to double link the records. Or add id_post to blog_post and image_post and remove id_blog_post and id_image_post from post.

What model you choose depends on the way you want to work with the tables and personal preference.